# PHP Session storage/access issue with Windows Network Mapping Shared Hard Drives

Tags: php, windows, apache, joomla

In my quest with mapping all my hard drives together is now working fine and I got nginx working fine pulling files from the other hard drive.

But I hit a new snag with PHP: it does not want to pull sessions from the external mapped hard drive.

My Z:/ drive is the drive I am trying to get php to pull and look at sessions in.

The website is Joomla 2.5
php version is 5.5.7 non threaded (64bit)
Apache is 2.4.6, mod_fcgid 2.3.9 (64bit)

Here is my mod_fcgi config and my php session config.
Mod_fcgid :

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
<IfModule fcgid_module>
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/server/php-5.5.7-nts"
FcgidInitialEnv PATH "c:/server/php-5.5.7-nts;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 0
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 0

FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
#FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
#FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidIOTimeout 3699
FcgidConnectTimeout 20
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0
FcgidProcessLifeTime 0
#FcgidMaxRequestInMem 1
FcgidWin32PreventOrphans On
#FcgidAuthenticatorAuthoritative Off
#FcgidAccessCheckerAuthoritative Off
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files ~ "\.php$>"
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper "c:/server/php-5.5.7-nts/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

PHP.ini :

```
session.save_path = "Z:/Windows/Temp"
```

Comment: While the "visual theme" of your question titles is cute, Stack Overflow has its own tagging system that we'd like you to use instead, please. Can you make your question title describe the question, rather than simply naming technologies? This will make it stand out in lists of questions. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and if you can explain your problem in more detail than "it does not want to pull sessions from the external mapped hard drive", that'd be great too.

Comment: Why did you edit my title... It is referring to a PHP problem not a Windows Mapped Hard drive issue. It is the fact that PHP can not connect to my external mapped hard drive and now you edited it ?

Comment: I already explained why. On Stack Overflow we do not write tags in titles; we write tags in _tags_. The title should _describe_ your problem. **Please make your question title describe the question, rather than simply naming technologies.**

Comment: I edited it is that better ?

Comment: Improvement in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry if my title was wrong it is a bit of a long question whats the max char limit for the titles ?